# Initialzing a custom binding w/ Core Data

Tags: core-data, swiftui

So far my only use of CoreData has been with lists and using fetch requests to populate them.

Well how would I go about saving one Bool as true or false for a view?

The bool will be used to fill a ⭐️

My idea is to pass a function I have on my CoreData class

```
 static func isFavoritedCheck(using movieID: Int, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Bool {
    let model = MovieData(context: context)
    return movieID == model.movieID && model.favorite == true 
}
```

To the custom binding in the view.. Is this possible or is using a FetchRequest the only way?

```
struct StarView: View {
@Binding var favorited: Bool
let movieID: Int
let storage: StorageProvider

init(movieID: Int, storage: StorageProvider) {
    self.movieID = movieID
    self.storage = storage
    _favorited = Binding    //stuck here
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, like this, you need wrap it as Binding!

```
struct StarView: View {
    
        let movieID: Int
        let storage: StorageProvider
        @Binding var favorited: Bool
        
        init(movieID: Int, storage: StorageProvider, favorited: Binding<Bool>) {
            self.movieID = movieID
            self.storage = storage
            _favorited = favorited     
        }

       var body: some View { 

          //. . . 

        }

}
```

Comment: You got half of the question but I didnt put `favorited` in the parameter list on purpose because I somehow wanted to give it a value from a CoreData property in the body of the init